# Python list: sorting on specifik column dont give the expected result

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm loading a csv file where each value is separated by ',' into a list.
Then I want to give a choice of which column in the list, the whole liste should be sorted on in order of size of the value in the kolumn. I use sort() and also tryed sorted However, I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

Use column 2 (then asked in the program)

```
#My code:
#This is liked csv-input of #wData.csv file:
wData=[['Country name','Ladder score','Logged GDP per capita','Social support','Healthy life expectancy','Freedom to make life choices','Generosity','Perceptions of corruption'],['Finland','7.804','10.792','0.969','71.150','0.961','0.019','0.182'],['Denmark','7.586','10.962','0.954','71.250','0.934','0.134','0.196'],['Iceland','7.530','10.896','0.983','72.050','0.936','0.211','0.668'],['Israel','7.473','10.639','0.943','72.697','0.809','-0.023','0.708'],['Netherlands','7.403','10.942','0.93','71.550','0.887','0.213','0.379'],['Sweden','7.395','10.883','0.939','72.150','0.948','0.165','0.202'],['Norway','7.315','11.088','0.943','71.500','0.947','0.141','0.283'],['Switzerland','7.240','11.164','0.92','72.900','0.891','0.027','0.266'],['Luxembourg','7.228','11.660','0.879','71.675','0.915','0.024','0.345'],['India','4.036','8.759','0.608','60.777','0.897','0.072','0.774'],['Madagascar','4.019','7.290','0.65','58.050','0.522','0.075','0.742'],['Lebanon','2.392','9.478','0.53','66.149','0.474','0.141','0.891'],['Afghanistan','1.859','7.324','0.341','54.712','0.382','-0.081','0.847']]

#print(wData)

print('What column to evaluate? ')
kolumn=int(input())
lander=[]
varden=[]
vardenAttVisa=8
nrPostLista = (len(wData)-1)

wData.sort(key=lambda x: x[int(kolumn)], reverse=False)
#sorted(WHR1Data,key=lambda x: x[kolumn])

for k in range(0,nrPostLista):
    print(f'|{wData[k+1][0]: <20} {"|": >4}{wData[k+1][kolumn]}{"|": >13}')
    lander.append(wData[k+1][0])
    varden.append(wData[k+1][kolumn])
```

#My results:
|Finland                 |10.792            |
|Sweden                  |10.883            |
|Iceland                 |10.896            |
|Netherlands             |10.942            |
|Denmark                 |10.962            |
|Norway                  |11.088            |
|Switzerland             |11.164            |
|Luxembourg              |11.660            |
|Madagascar              |7.290            |
|Afghanistan             |7.324            |
|India                   |8.759            |
|Lebanon                 |9.478            |
|Country name            |Logged GDP per capita            |

#wanted/expected result should be like:
|Luxembourg |11,660 |
|Switzerland |11,164 |
|Norway |11,088 |
|Denmark |10,962 |
...
|Madagascar |7,290 |

BR
Jappen

Comment: please fix your question so it containes acutally runnable code. Most importantly imports for the libraries used and not typos!

Comment: now should it be runnable :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to use `pandas` for this task. It simplifies the code and it's more flexible. Also instead of using an `int` to select the column, you could use a `string`. Here is a possible implementation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('wData.csv')

print('Enter the column name to evaluate?')
column = input()


df = df.sort_values(by=[column], ascending=True, ignore_index=True)
result = df.loc[:, ['Country name', column]]
print(result)
```

> Result:

```
Enter the column name to evaluate?
Logged GDP per capita

   Country name  Logged GDP per capita
0    Luxembourg                 11.660
1   Switzerland                 11.164
2        Norway                 11.088
3       Denmark                 10.962
4   Netherlands                 10.942
5       Iceland                 10.896
6        Sweden                 10.883
7       Finland                 10.792
8        Israel                 10.639
9       Lebanon                  9.478
10        India                  8.759
11  Afghanistan                  7.324
12   Madagascar                  7.290
```

Answer (score 0):

All your data are in string format, so they will sort "alphabetically", and not by numbers. This should work:

```
#My code:
#This is liked csv-input of #wData.csv file:
wData=[['Country name','Ladder score','Logged GDP per capita','Social support','Healthy life expectancy','Freedom to make life choices','Generosity','Perceptions of corruption'],['Finland','7.804','10.792','0.969','71.150','0.961','0.019','0.182'],['Denmark','7.586','10.962','0.954','71.250','0.934','0.134','0.196'],['Iceland','7.530','10.896','0.983','72.050','0.936','0.211','0.668'],['Israel','7.473','10.639','0.943','72.697','0.809','-0.023','0.708'],['Netherlands','7.403','10.942','0.93','71.550','0.887','0.213','0.379'],['Sweden','7.395','10.883','0.939','72.150','0.948','0.165','0.202'],['Norway','7.315','11.088','0.943','71.500','0.947','0.141','0.283'],['Switzerland','7.240','11.164','0.92','72.900','0.891','0.027','0.266'],['Luxembourg','7.228','11.660','0.879','71.675','0.915','0.024','0.345'],['India','4.036','8.759','0.608','60.777','0.897','0.072','0.774'],['Madagascar','4.019','7.290','0.65','58.050','0.522','0.075','0.742'],['Lebanon','2.392','9.478','0.53','66.149','0.474','0.141','0.891'],['Afghanistan','1.859','7.324','0.341','54.712','0.382','-0.081','0.847']]

def change_to_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return x

wData=[[change_to_float(y) for y in x] for x in wData]

print('What column to evaluate? ')
kolumn=int(input())
lander=[]
varden=[]
vardenAttVisa=8
nrPostLista = (len(wData)-1)

headers = wdata[0]
wData = sorted(wData[1:], key=lambda x: x[kolumn], reverse=True)
wData.insert(0, headers)

for k in range(0,nrPostLista):
    print(f'|{wData[k+1][0]: <20} {"|": >4}{wData[k+1][kolumn]}{"|": >13}')
    lander.append(wData[k+1][0])
    varden.append(wData[k+1][kolumn])
```

Answer (score -2):

here is a working (simplefid) version:

```py
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as fp:
        return [_.split(',') for _ in fp.readlines()[1:]]


wData = read_file('wdata.csv')

column=int(input('What column to evaluate? '))

wData.sort(key=lambda x: x[column])

for e in wData:
    print(f'| {e[0]:20} | {e[1]:>7} | {e[2]:>7}')
```

Output:

```
What column to evaluate? 2
| Israel               |   7.473 |  10.639
| Finland              |   7.804 |  10.792
| Sweden               |   7.395 |  10.883
| Iceland              |   7.530 |  10.896
| Netherlands          |   7.403 |  10.942
| Denmark              |   7.586 |  10.962
| Norway               |   7.315 |  11.088
| Switzerland          |   7.240 |  11.164
| Luxembourg           |   7.228 |  11.660
| Madagascar           |   4.019 |   7.290
| Afghanistan          |   1.859 |   7.324
| India                |   4.036 |   8.759
| Lebanon              |   2.392 |   9.478
```

EDIT: without more parsing on the csv file the output is of course just sorted as a string, not as a number.